# FLUTTER - Developing an app on a macbook, can you debug on an iPhone AND on an ANDROID (Samsung phone) phone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, debugging

I am developing a flutter app on a MacBook, using VISUAL STUDIO. I debug it on an iPhone XS MAX. I would like to debug it on a SAMSUNG A21S as well, to see if both apps work (the IOS one and the Android one). So far, I have tried the android one on a WINDOWS computer.

Anyone knows if it's possible to debug on a the Samsung A21 using my MacBook ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it ? Is there a website that explains it ? Is it complicated to set up ?

Comment: why can't you just side load the app to the android device ? i imagine it would work similar to how you're doing it for ios, can't you just connect the device and deploy to it ?

Comment: the macbook doesn't seem to recognize the phone when I plug it in via USB.

Comment: Enable USB debugging on your android mobile. It will show up in VS Code status. If it does not show, open Android Studio and reconnect the USB. After that, it will show up on VS Code whenever you connect USB.

Comment: Yes my Android mobile is ready for development. I use it on a Windows PC with Visual Code

Comment: there are some adb drivers you can download for android when using mac, not sure where they are located by try searching online for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a problem with recognizing the device, you have to set up ADB manually. Use this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) to set up.